# Vue использование частей template повторно

Tags: vue.js, шаблоны

Подскажите правильный (или best practice) способ использования повторяемого кода в шаблонах Vue компонентов

Скажем, у меня есть два компонента:

## User.vue

```html
<template>
<div>
    <app-title>Hi, Username!</app-title>
    <p>Nice to see u again!</p>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  import Title from "./Title"
  export default {
    components: {
      appTitle: Title
    }
  }
</script>
```

## Book.vue

```html
<template>
<div>
    <app-title>The book's page</app-title>
    <p>...text about this book...</p>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  import Title from "./Title"
  export default {
    components: {
      appTitle: Title
    }
  }
</script>
```

## и компонент заголовка страницы Title.vue

```html
<template>
<div>
    <h1 class="my-super-incredible-page-title">
         <slot></slot>
    </h1>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {}
</script>
```

Я использую **Title.vue** исключительно для того, чтобы все заголовки на сайте выглядели одинаково. В него можно добавить, скажем, breadcrumbs или что-то еще. Если вдруг я решу, что мне нужно выводить загловки не в h1, а, скажем, в h2, мне достаточно изменить только один файл

В этой ситуации мне не нравится, что приходится импортировать компонент **Title.vue** дважды (а в теории - *n* раз, где *n* - количество уникальных страниц)

С одной стороны, я могу импортировать **Title.vue** глобально в моем app.js, но правильный ли это подход? Кроме компонента с заголовком, у меня могут быть компоненты чего угодно, например, я хочу выводить аватар пользователя на странице 3 раза и везде одинаково

может есть что-то вроде такого варианта ↓↓↓

Есть ли какая-то возможность передавать импортированные компоненты от родителя к дочернему, как показано ниже:

```html
<!-- ################################# Parent.vue ################################# -->
    <template>
<div>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <p>
        <!-- some html here -->
    </p>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from "./Header"
import Title from "./Title"
export default {
    components: {
        appHeader: Header,
        appTitle: Title,
    }
}
</script>


<!-- ################################# Header.vue ################################# -->

<div>
    <app-title></app-title>
    <sub> subtitle here</sub>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {}
</script>
```

Как видно из примера, я не импортирую в дочернем компоненте Header компонент Title. Конечно, в данном случае будет ошибка, т.к. **vue** скажет что тег **app-title** не определен

Comment: В глобальной регистрации компонентов вроде нет ничего плохо. Все варианты рабочие, гляньте еще [такой](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: Интересное решение... А есть какой-то способ подключить глобально нужные компоненты в одном внешнем файле (этакий js файл только для импорта глобальных компонентов), а потом этот файл импортировать уже в само приложение? @Doigrales

Comment: Разве что, объединить все базовые компоненты в один файл и подключать их там где это необходимо.

Comment: @Doigrales, спасибо за подсказки

Comment: > В этой ситуации мне не нравится, что приходится импортировать компонент Title.vue дважды (а в теории - n раз, где n - количество уникальных страниц)


А должно нравиться, ибо явное лучше неявного. Вы к этому придете, когда у вас компонентов за 100+ перевалит в приложении.

Comment: @yarkov_aleksei должно понравиться импорт постоянный на всех страницах одного компонента? Если это единственный рабочий враиант, то наверное понравится когда-нибудь ._.